# Wrapping software into a suite of unlockable sub-applications via product keys

Tags: android, software-development, project-management, product-management

Not sure if this is the site to ask this, however, I am a software developer for a company that is developing an Android app for our customers to use. Our app is pretty much feature-locked now, so what our company is proposing now is to wrap the application into a suite of three different sub-applications. Since this isn't coding related, I think it is more appropriate to ask it here than at Stack Overflow.

Now, if we go this route, each sub-application would require a separate product key to unlock them. I have never made such applications before that require unlocking portions with product keys.

I was wondering, are there any built-in methods or cheap/free external tools for Android that we can use for the product keys can be validated for each of the portions of the app? We would like to use an offline solution that can correctly validate a product key without having to re-enter it each time. The reason we want an offline solution is because this product suite will run on 10' tablets (not phones), and our customers will often use this product suite in areas without Wi-Fi access.

I would like to know, what solutions are available, either built into Android or as an external solution?